# Associative array - Tree Vs HashTable

Tags: arrays, tree

Associative arrays are usually implemented with Hashtables. But recently, I came to know that they can also be implemented using Trees. Can someone explain how to implement using a Tree?

1. Should we use a simple binary tree or BST?
2. How do we represent the keys in the tree? Do we calculate a hashfunction on the key and insert the (key,value) based on the integer hash value?
3. If we assume that we calculate hash value and insert into tree, why do people say trees or ordered? What order does it preserve and how? What does this ordering buy us?

Lastly, one general question about the hash table. People say the search time is O(1) in hash table. But when we say O(1), do we take into account of calculating the hash value before we look up using the hash value? If our key is string, then, we need to visit all the characters of the string to find the hashvalue. So, to search an element, won't it take O(n)+O(1) time?

Comment: Even for associative arrays we deal with set of keys to insert, delete and search. Corresponding values are irrelevant for all these operations. Therefore, you can use the same data structures, say for a set of Strings and for a set of (String, Int). In both cases you can use BST, Hash-tables, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash table solutions will take the hash of objects stored in them (its important to note that the hash is a primitive, often an integer or long) and use that hash as an array index, and store a reference to the object at that index in the array.  To solve the collision problem, indices in this array will often contain linked list nodes that hold the actual references.

Checking if an object is in the array is as simple as hashing it, looking in the index referred to by the hash, and comparing equality with each object that's there, an operation that runs in amortized constant time, because the hash table can grow larger if collisions are beginning to accumulate.

Now for your questions.

### Question 1

> Should we use a simple binary tree or a BST?

BST stands for Binary Search Tree.  The difference between it and a "simple" binary tree is that it is strictly ordered.  Optimal implementations will also attempt to keep the tree balanced.  Searching through a balanced, ordered tree is much easier than an unordered one, because certain assumptions about the location of the target element that cannot be made in an unordered tree.  You should use a BST if practical.

### Question 2

> How do we represent the keys in the tree? Do we calculate a hashfunction on the key and insert the (key,value) based on the integer hash value?

That would be what a hash table does.  Even hash tables must store the keys by value for equality checking due to the possibility of collisions.  The BST would not store hashes at all because under all nonsimple circumstances, determining sort order from the hash values would be very difficult.  You would use (key, value) pairs without any hashing.

### Question 3

> If we assume that we calculate hash value and insert into tree, why do people say trees or ordered? What order does it preserve and how? What does this ordering buy us?

As you noticed, it doesn't work that way.  So we store the value of the key instead of the hash.  Ordering the tree (as opposed to an unordered tree) gives us a huge advantage when searching (O(log(N)) instead of O(N)).  In an unordered structure, some specific element must be exhaustively searched for because it could reside anywhere in the structure.  In an ordered structure, it will only exist above keys whose values are less than its, and below keys whose values are greater.  Consider a textbook.  Would you have an easier or harder time jumping to a specific page if the pages were in a random order?

### Question 4

> If our key is string, then, we need to visit all the characters of the string to find the hashvalue. So, to search an element, won't it take O(n)+O(1) time?

I've asked myself the same question before, and it actually depends on the hash function.  "Amortized constant" lookup's worst case time is:

```
O(H) + O(C)
```

O(H) is the worst case complexity of the hash function.  A smart hash function might look at only the first few dozen characters of a string, or the last few, or some in the middle, or something.  It's not necessary for the hash function to be secure, it just has to be deterministic (i.e. return the same value for the identical objects).  Regardless of how good your function is, you will get collisions anyway, so if you can trade off doing a huge amount of extra work for a slightly more collidable function, it's often worth it.

O(C) is the worst case complexity of comparing the keys.  An unsuccessful lookup knows that there are no matches because no entry in the table exists for its hash value.  A successful lookup however always must compare the provided key with the ones in the table, otherwise the possibility exists that the key is not actually a match but merely a collision.  Worst possible case is if there are multiple collisions for one hash value, the provided key must be compared with all of the stored colliding keys one after another until a match is found or all comparisons fail.  This gotcha is why it's only amortized constant time instead of just constant time: as the table grows, the chances of having collisions decreases, so this happens less frequently, and the average time required to search some collection of elements will always tend toward a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Somehow I missed this post for a long time and seen it only today.

Answer (score 0):

When people say hash is O(1) (or you could say O(1+0n) and tree is O(log n), they mean where n is size of collection.
You are right in that it takes O(m) (where m is length of currently examinded string) aditional work, but usualy m has some upper bound and n tends to get large. So m can be considered constant for both of implementations.
And m is in absolute terms more influential in tree implementation. Because you compare with key in every node you visit, where in hash you only compute hash and compare whole key with all values in one bucket determined by hash (with good hash function and big enough table, there should usualy be only one value there).